# How is $\partial/\partial t$ a vector?

Tags: differential-geometry, vectors, mathematics, vector-fields

How is $\partial_t=\partial/\partial t$ a (Killing) vector in some coordinate system?

I know $\partial f/\partial t$ is the partial derivative of $f$ with respect to $t$.

But how about  $\partial/\partial t$? Is it still the partial derivative with respect to $t$? But of what?

Comment: In what connection have you seen this? Are you sure nothing was written in front of the $\partial/\partial t$ symbol?

Comment: In more abstract treatments of differential geometry, vectors are *defined* to be derivatives with respect to a parameter along some curve. Admittedly this is a somewhat strange concept when you first meet it – I suggest you pick up a more formal text on GR!

Comment: In more detail, the identification of vectors and differential operators is as follows: Given a directional vector (as opposed to "position vector", which isn't really a vector), for example a vector $V\in\mathbb {R}^3$ and a point $p \in\mathbb {R}^3$ we can take the directional derivative of some function and evaluate that at $p $. This produces the differential operator associated with $V $. There exists a coordinate system where this derivative is a partial derivative at $p $. It can be shown that every differential operator with evaluation at $p $ comes from some vector in this way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\partial/\partial t$ is **not** a partial derivative. It is just notation. What you used to write as $\hat u_i$, or $\hat x_i$, is now written as
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i} \tag{1}
$$

In other words, $\partial/\partial x^i$ is a standard vector, but with a new, different notation. This notation is convenient for several reasons; for example, changing local coordinates looks like the chain rule (which ultimately is not really a coincidence, but the result of the fact that the tangent space is spanned by gradients).

Also, we usually define vectors as derivations, so that for a certain coordinate chart,
$$
v(f)\equiv\sum_i v_i \frac{\partial f}{\partial x^i} \tag{2}
$$
which is consistent with
$$
v=v_i\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i} \tag{3}
$$
where in $(2)$ the symbol $\partial$ denotes a true derivative, and in $(3)$ it denotes a basis vector.

---

If you will, in the old notation you can write the Killing vector as $k=(1,0,0,0)$ instead of $k=\partial/\partial t$. It is the exact same thing.

Answer (score 0):

A vector $\xi^\mu$ is associated with the differential operator $\xi^\mu\partial_\mu$, which is $\partial_t$ for $\xi^\mu=\delta^\mu_0$ so  $\nabla^\mu\xi^\nu=0$. Thus $\nabla^\mu\xi^\nu+\nabla^\nu\xi^\mu=0$, making $\xi^\mu$ a Killing vector.